# Attachment optional in REST WS

Tags: web-services, rest, jakarta-ee

I have a POST WS in REST, with Attachment file defined like this :

```
@POST
@ElementClass(request = AWsDTO.class)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response createA(@Multipart(value = MULTIPART_DTO_PART, type = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) AWsDTO aWsDTO,
        @Multipart(MULTIPART_FILE_PART) Attachment file) throws Exception {
...

}
```

I want that attachment is optional. How to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it :

```
@Multipart(value = MULTIPART_FILE_PART, required = false) Attachment file)
```